# inconsistent random 'load' failures in Ruby 1.9.3-p448

Tags: ruby, load, runtime-error, ruby-1.9.3, non-deterministic

For purposes of asking another question, I was loading and re-loading the same file over and over again. I noticed a fair fraction of the time the `load` would fail, for no apparent reason whatsoever. This is `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]`, pretty much as it comes packaged with metasploit.

Here's a transcript of the irb session (the source file is appended below) - for this transcript, I was doing nothing but hitting the `up-arrow` key and hitting return, repeating the same `load` command at about one-second intervals:

```
C:\test-ruby>
C:\test-ruby>irb
irb(main):001:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
RuntimeError:
        from test-pack.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):2:in `load'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/metasploit/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):006:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
RuntimeError:
        from test-pack.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):6:in `load'
        from (irb):6
        from C:/metasploit/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):007:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
RuntimeError:
        from test-pack.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):7:in `load'
        from (irb):7
        from C:/metasploit/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):008:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):009:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):010:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
RuntimeError:
        from test-pack.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):10:in `load'
        from (irb):10
        from C:/metasploit/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):011:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):012:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):013:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):014:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):015:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):016:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):017:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):018:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):019:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):020:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):021:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
RuntimeError:
        from test-pack.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):21:in `load'
        from (irb):21
        from C:/metasploit/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):022:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):023:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):024:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):025:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):026:0> load 'test-pack.rb'
=> true
irb(main):027:0>
```

And here's the test-pack.rb code - line 11 of this file happens to be the `fail unless $bits.encoding == $ptr.encoding` line (which one would think ought to be deterministic, at least):

```
$save = "xyz\0"
$ptr = [$save].pack("p")
$ptrs = [$ptr, $ptr]

$bits = ""
$bits << $ptr

fail unless $bits == $ptr
fail unless $bits.encoding == $ptr.encoding

def x(s)
  s.bytes.to_a.map {|p| ("0" + p.to_s(16))[-2,2]}.reverse.join(".")
end

def see(tag, p)
  puts "f#{tag}  #{x(p)} #{p.encoding} #{p.class} #{x([p.object_id].pack("I"))}"
  p.unpack("p")[0]
end


def f1
  see 1, $bits[0, 4]
end

def f2
  p = $bits[0, 4]
  see 2, p
end

def f3
  p = $bits[0, 4].dup
  see 3, p
end

def f4
  p = $bits[0, 4].bytes.to_a.join
  see 4, p
end

def f5
  p = $bits[0, 4].bytes.to_a.join.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
  see 5, p
end

def f6
  p = $bits[0, 4].bytes.to_a.pack("CCCC")
  see 13, p
end

def f7
  see 7, $ptr.clone
end


def f11
  see 11, $ptr
end

def f12
  p = $ptr
  see 12, p
end

def f13
  see 13, $ptrs[0]
end

def f14
  see 14, $ptrs[1]
end

def f15
  see 15, $ptr.dup
end

def f16
  see 16, $ptrs[1].dup
end

def f17
  see 17, $ptrs[1].clone
end
```